# Two dimensional aggregate in R? (to create Heatmap)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a table with two factor columns that I would like to aggregate into a table that's easy for heatmap mapping.

This table has for example has the following format

```
 City         Date           Revenue     Costs       Manager 
 ____         ____            _______    ______       ___
 New York     Feb 1           2000        200        Stuart
 San Fran     Feb 3           1200        300        John
 Boston       Feb 1           1500        400        Mike
 Boston       Feb 1           1300        200        Cissy
```

and so forth

I would like to have an 2-D aggregated table in this format by revenue

```
Sum Revenue  New York     San Fran     Boston   
 ____         ____           ____       ____
 Feb 1        2000             0        2800
 Feb 2          0              0          0
 Feb 3          0             1200        0
```

Is there an easy way of doing this, or am I stuck using loops?

Comment: not just reshaping, by aggregating by date, city as well

Comment: Thank you Arun, the two simple steps of aggregate + reshape saved me the hassle of writing a long loop function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Arun suggests in the comments, `reshape` will do this for you.

```
d<-read.table(text='City         Date           Revenue     Costs
"New York"     "Feb 1"           2000        200
"San Fran"     "Feb 3"           1200        300
Boston       "Feb 1"           1500        400', header=TRUE)
reshape(d[! names(d) %in% 'Costs'], idvar='Date', timevar='City', direction='wide')
#    Date Revenue.New York Revenue.San Fran Revenue.Boston
# 1 Feb 1             2000               NA           1500
# 2 Feb 3               NA             1200             NA
```

If there are multiple entries for City/Date that you want to combine first, you can use `aggregate`.

```
d<-read.table(text='City         Date           Revenue     Costs
"New York"     "Feb 1"           2000        200
"New York"     "Feb 1"           1000        100
"San Fran"     "Feb 3"           1200        300
Boston       "Feb 1"           1500        400', header=TRUE)
dd<-with(d, aggregate(Revenue, by=list(City=City, Date=Date), sum))
#     City     Date  x
# 1   Boston   Feb 1 1500
# 2 New York   Feb 1 3000
# 3 San Fran   Feb 3 1200
ddd<-reshape(dd, idvar='Date', timevar='City', direction='wide')
#    Date x.Boston x.New York x.San Fran
# 1 Feb 1     1500       3000         NA
# 3 Feb 3       NA         NA       1200
```

Then replace `NA`s with `0`.

```
ddd[is.na(ddd)] <- 0
#    Date x.Boston x.New York x.San Fran
# 1 Feb 1     1500       3000          0
# 3 Feb 3        0          0       1200
```

To address the point @Arun brings up below, prior to the previous step you could fill missing Date using the `merge` function.

```
missing.Dates <- c('Feb 2')
ddd<-merge(ddd, data.frame(Date=missing.Dates), by='Date', all=TRUE)
#   Date x.Boston x.New York x.San Fran
#1 Feb 1     1500       3000         NA
#2 Feb 3       NA         NA       1200
#3 Feb 2       NA         NA         NA
ddd[is.na(ddd)] <- 0
#    Date x.Boston x.New York x.San Fran
# 1 Feb 1     1500       3000          0
# 2 Feb 3        0          0       1200
# 3 Feb 2        0          0          0
```

Comment: the problem is with "Feb 2"... (which would probably mean that the Date column must generated as Dates..?)

Comment: @Arun I suppose the OP could start with an empty matrix, fill all dates, and then overwrite each row for which there's a matching date in the `ddd` array.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Another way might be to `merge` with a `data.frame` containing the missing Date values.